# Weird error using CONVERT function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database set up as

```
Account (accountNo, ownerNo, balance)
Owner (ownerNo, firstName, lastName)
Event (id, accountNo, event, amount, eventDate)
```

So I am trying to List all transactions (Event table) for July for account 1 by doing so;

```
CREATE VIEW FourA AS 
   SELECT 
      id, accountNo, event, amount, 
      CONVERT(varchar, eventDate, 103) AS eventDate
   FROM 
      Event
   WHERE 
      accountNo = 1 AND eventDate >= '01/07/2014' AND eventDate < '31/07/2014'
```

The first time I ran this, it ran perfectly. Now I'm getting an error for the `CONVERT` function:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

HOWEVER! When I run:

```
select 
    CONVERT(varchar, eventDate, 103) AS eventDate
from 
    Event
```

it gives the perfect result of:

```
eventDate
01/01/2014
07/11/2014
08/01/2014 
01/01/2014
07/10/2014
08/02/2014
```

So clearly it's not wrong. But why do I keep getting this weird error? Does anyone know?

NOTE: this is in SQL Server

Comment: Side note:you should use appropriate data types for your columns. Storing a `DateTime` value in a `Varchar` will bite you repeatedly. Don't fix this. Fix the tables.

Comment: Agreed. Band-Aids don't last very long.

Comment: @MikeW I actually do have it stored as a DateTime value, however the problem is presenting it in a nice format. Since it shows up as 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 Unless is there a way to store it as MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: If not `datetime`, why not just `date` data type?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not within your CONVERT function. The problem is because of the implicit conversion of the date literals in your WHERE clause. I recommend you use the YYYYMMDD format for the date literals:

```
CREATE VIEW FourA AS 
SELECT id, accountNo, event, amount, CONVERT(varchar(10), eventDate, 103) AS eventDate
FROM Event
WHERE accountNo = 1 AND eventDate >= '20140701' AND eventDate < '20140731'
```

As commented below, if you do not want the time component in the result string use VARCHAR(10) when converting the date

Comment: Best to CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),eventDate,103) as the conversion leads to VARCHAR of length 10.

Comment: Only you know what is in your table... I can only guess